# Is MaxMind's GeoIP2 java API thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, geoip, maxmind

I know that it's possible to make the GeoIPLite legacy Java API thread-safe by using certain caching parameters, but the GeoIP2 docs for Java or C don't mention the word "thread" at all.

I'd like to be able to build() a DatabaseReader once and then do city() on it in several different threads. Is this safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the GeoIP2 Java API is thread safe. It is recommended to open one reader and share that between threads. This is documented in the [README.md](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java#multi-threaded-use).

Comment: Greg link is dead.